# What is the fallacy in assuming the convergence of the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + |\sin(n)|}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So if we assume that $q = \min \{ |\sin k| : k \in \mathbb N\}$ 
So $q > 0$.

Then the series  $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + |\sin(n)|}}\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + q}} $ 
This converges because it is a p series with power of n being greater than 1.

Comment: How you know $q>0$? And also the minimum of the set might not exist. So using infimum would be better..

Comment: $q=0$ so cannot deduce result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fallacy is that $\{|\sin k|:k\in\mathbb N\}$ doesn't have a minimum. It contains values arbitrarily close to (but not equal to) $0$. So the best lower bound you can put on the power is exactly $1$, which doesn't help determine convergence.

Comment: Ok, but how do we know that an infimum/minimum doesn't exist for the sequence/set. Is there a term for such sequences?

Comment: @MathLearner in this case, because you can find multiples of $\pi$ which are arbitrarily close to integers, and then the corresponding integer has a sine very close to $0$. To see that the first statment is true: suppose you want to find a multiple of $\pi$ within $1/1000000$ of an integer then take the first $1000000$ multiples of $\pi$ and look at their fractional parts. Some two of these fractional parts must differ by at most $1/1000000$, so you can just take the difference of the two multiples, which is another multiple of $\pi$.